# Spring data query method creation

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

What is the correct way to query on login field for both Sender and Receiver (Sender and Receiver are instances of the same object type)

`Page<Message> findBySenderLoginOrReceiverLogin(String login, Pageable pageable);`

Thanks

Comment: You're missing one parameter, try: `Page<Message> findBySenderLoginOrReceiverLogin(String senderLogin, String receiverLogin, Pageable pageable);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query method creation is extensively explained in the [official docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation).

As @Marc Tarin suggested this answers my question:

```
Page<Message> findBySenderLoginOrReceiverLogin(String SenderLogin, String ReceiverLogin, Pageable pageable);
```